# asio::async_connect vs asio::connect. Is asio::connect a non-blocking sync?

Tags: c++, asio

I'm using the asio 1.18.1 standalone version (no boost) and I wonder about the difference between `asio::connect` and `asio::async_connect`.

I can tell myself why I need async for my server, because the point of async is being able to deal with a lot of data on a lot of different connections at the same time.

But when it comes to the client, I really need just one non-blocking thread and isn't async for just one thread useless? Is `asio::connect` a non-blocking sync, because that's what I really need? If it's a blocking sync, then I would rather choose the `asio::async_connect`. Same question about `asio::async_read` and `asio::async_write`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm using the asio 1.18.1 standalone version (no boost) and I wonder about the difference between asio::connect and asio::async_connect.

`asio::connect` attempts to connect a socket at the point of call and will block until connection is established. In other words, if it takes eg 20 seconds to resolve a DNS address, it will block for the entire duration.

`asio::async_connect` will simply queue up connection request and will not actually do anything until you call `io_context.run()` (or other functions, such as `run_once()`, etc).

> I can tell myself why I need async for my server, because the point of async is being able to deal with a lot of data on a lot of different connections at the same time.

I can neither confirm nor deny that.

> But when it comes to the client, I really need just one non-blocking thread and isn't async for just one thread useless?

Not necessarily. If you want to do other things on the same thread, eg show connection progress, execute periodic timer or run interactive GUI, etc. If you call `asio::connect`, your GUI will freeze until the function returns. You can choose to call `asio::connect` on a separate thread than your GUI, but then you need to worry about thread synchronization, locks, mutexes, etc.

> Is asio::connect a non-blocking sync, because that's what I really need?

I don't really understand this question, but `asio::connect` is blocking.

> If it's a blocking sync, then I would rather choose the asio::async_connect. Same question about asio::async_read and asio::async_write.

`asio::connect`, `asio::read` and `asio::write` are all blocking. In other words, they will execute at the point of call and will block until done.

`asio::async_connect`, `asio::async_read` and `asio::async_write` are their async (non-blocking) counterparts. When you call either one, they will be queued for execution and will be executed once you call `io_context.run()`. (I am simplifying a bit, but that's the basic concept.)